# android rootview malfunctionning

Tags: android, listview, rootview

I'm creating a fragment that contains two `listview`s ,the two in a `linearlayout` that has as `orientation:horizontal`;
the second `listview` is in a `horizontalscrollview`;
**the problem is in the second `listview`**;

I should have in each row of the listview 6 `textview` there's one 100 `textview` in the first row. The other rows have the correct number of `textview`s.

When I was debugging, I deduced that the problem is in my adapter in the `getview` function, I'm not sure what the exact issue is.

Here is the adapter of the `listview` that I'm referring to:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    if(row==null)
    {
        row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_live_2,parent,false);

    }
    List<String> stages = getItem(position);
    LinearLayout linear_layout= (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.layout_stages);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 71);
    layoutparams.setMargins(0,0,10,0);
    for(int j=0;j<stages.size();++j)
    {
        TextView textView =new TextView (row.getContext());
        textView.setText(stages.get(j));
        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
        linear_layout.addView(textView);
    }

    return row;
}
```